# Trying to calculate sunrise...ain't getting the right answer

Tags: java

This is my current code:

```
    public class Sunpos {
   final private double Pi = Math.PI;
   final private double eul = 2.71828182845904523552 ;
   final private double sonauf = 90;
   final private double RAD = 0.017453292519943295769236907684886;

public double sunrisefinal (double Breitengrad, double Laengengrad, int tagzahl, int sommerzeit, int nacht) {

    double lngHour = Laengengrad/15;
    double t = tagzahl + ((6 - lngHour)/24);

    // double ab = tagzahl + ((18 - lngHour)/24);
    double M = (0.9856 * t) - 3.289;
    double L = M + (1.916 * Math.sin(M)) + (0.020 * Math.sin(2 * M)) + 282.634;

        if (L >= 359) { L -= 360; }
        else if (L < 0) { L += 360; }  

    double RA = (Math.atan(0.91764 * Math.tan(Pi/180)*L));

        if (RA >= 359) { RA -= 360; }
        else if (RA < 0) { RA += 360; }

    double Lquadrant = (Math.floor(L/90)*90);
    double RAquadrant = (Math.floor(RA/90))*90;
    RA = RA + (Lquadrant - RAquadrant);
    RA = RA/15;

    double sinDec = 0.39782 * Math.sin((Pi/180)*L);
    double cosDec = (180/Pi)*(Math.cos(Math.asin(sinDec)));
    double cosH = (Math.cos((Pi/180)*sonauf)-(sinDec*Math.sin((Pi/180)*Breitengrad)))/(cosDec * Math.cos((Pi/180)*Breitengrad));
    double H = 360 - Math.acos(cosH);
    H /= 15;

    double T = H + RA -(0.06571 * t) - 6.622;
    double UTC = T - lngHour;

        if (UTC >= 23) { UTC -= 24; }
        else if (UTC < 0) { UTC += 24; }

    double locTime = UTC; // Fuer die schweiz!
    System.out.println(locTime);
    return(0);


}
```

The inputs are the following: ( 50, 10, 294, 1, 0). The last 2 can be ignored.

Now I am basing this on the following page:
http://williams.best.vwh.net/sunrise_sunset_algorithm.htm

The code should be complete according to the site, but I don't get anywhere near the supposed results. I should get around 7.5 for today but I'm getting a 9.358.

Now, that might be because something with radiants/degrees? I can't quite get my Mind into that, as I've been trying to insert those converters (Pi/180)  into the code, without any usable result.

Can anyone tell me where to put them or point me in the right direction? I've spent waaaay too much time on this already, and now I'm so close.

Comment: just as a small word of advice - while it shouldn't matter to the compiler so-long-as the code is technically correct, your syntax style makes it very difficult to easily read your code and spot any mistakes. Add some spacing between lines of logical blocks of code, don't randomly indent some snippets of code and not others, etc. Readability is far better than short conciseness.

Comment: It is a bit too much to ask SO to debug an algorithm like that :) But here's the sunrise/sunset algorithm that I ported to Java that works (per my own testing) - https://gist.github.com/zhong-j-yu/2232343b14a5b5ef5b9d

Comment: @SnakeDoc Ive edited and added some spacings. Im just working on for some hours and Im pretty exhausted to think about that. Sorry!

Comment: @bayou.io I'll take a look at it, thanks!
I mainly am trying to see if Ive overlooked something...which I probably have, but am just too tired to notice.

Comment: comparing our code, it seems that indeed the problem is the unit of angle

Comment: Sometimes it's helpful to insert a bunch of `System.out.println()`'s and print out each of the variables after every calculation. This way you can run the calculation by hand and match it up against your printed output at each step of the way. This can help identify exactly where in your code it went off the rails, so-to-speak. (Just remember to take the debug println()'s out afterwards! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll just post my implementation here in case people need it (ported from the same source as yours)

https://gist.github.com/zhong-j-yu/2232343b14a5b5ef5b9d

```
    public class SunRiseSetAlgo
    {
        static double calcSunrise(int dayOfYear, double localOffset, double latitude, double longitude)
        {
            return calc(dayOfYear, localOffset, latitude, longitude, true);
        }
        static double calcSunset(int dayOfYear, double localOffset, double latitude, double longitude)
        {
            return calc(dayOfYear, localOffset, latitude, longitude, false);
        }

        // http://williams.best.vwh.net/sunrise_sunset_algorithm.htm
        static double calc(int dayOfYear, double localOffset, double latitude, double longitude, boolean rise)
        {
            //1. first calculate the day of the year

    //        int N1 = floor(275 * month / 9.0);
    //        int N2 = floor((month + 9) / 12.0);
    //        int N3 = (1 + floor((year - 4 * floor(year / 4.0) + 2) / 3.0));
    //        int N = N1 - (N2 * N3) + day - 30;
            int N = dayOfYear;

            //2. convert the longitude to hour value and calculate an approximate time

            double lngHour = longitude / 15;
            double t = rise?
                N + (( 6 - lngHour) / 24) :
                N + ((18 - lngHour) / 24);

            //3. calculate the Sun's mean anomaly

            double M = (0.9856 * t) - 3.289;

            //4. calculate the Sun's true longitude

            double L = M + (1.916 * sin(M)) + (0.020 * sin(2 * M)) + 282.634;
            L = mod(L, 360);

            //5a. calculate the Sun's right ascension
            double RA = atan(0.91764 * tan(L));
            RA = mod(RA, 360);

            //5b. right ascension value needs to be in the same quadrant as L
            double Lquadrant  = (floor( L/90)) * 90;
            double RAquadrant = (floor(RA/90)) * 90;
            RA = RA + (Lquadrant - RAquadrant);

            //5c. right ascension value needs to be converted into hours
            RA = RA / 15;

            //6. calculate the Sun's declination
            double sinDec = 0.39782 * sin(L);
            double cosDec = cos(asin(sinDec));

            //7a. calculate the Sun's local hour angle
            double zenith = 90 + 50.0/60;
            double cosH = (cos(zenith) - (sinDec * sin(latitude))) / (cosDec * cos(latitude));

            if (cosH >  1)
              throw new Error("the sun never rises on this location (on the specified date");
            if (cosH < -1)
              throw new Error("the sun never sets on this location (on the specified date");

            //7b. finish calculating H and convert into hours
            double H = rise?
                360 - acos(cosH) :
                acos(cosH);
            H = H / 15;

            //8. calculate local mean time of rising/setting
            double T = H + RA - (0.06571 * t) - 6.622;

            //9. adjust back to UTC
            double UT = T - lngHour;

            //10. convert UT value to local time zone of latitude/longitude
            double localT = UT + localOffset;
            localT = mod(localT, 24);
            return localT;
        }

        static int floor(double d){ return (int)Math.floor(d); }

        static double sin(double degree)
        {
            return Math.sin(degree*Math.PI/180);
        }
        static double cos(double degree)
        {
            return Math.cos(degree*Math.PI/180);
        }
        static double tan(double degree)
        {
            return Math.tan(degree*Math.PI/180);
        }
        static double atan(double x)
        {
            return Math.atan(x) *180/Math.PI;
        }
        static double asin(double x)
        {
            return Math.asin(x) *180/Math.PI;
        }
        static double acos(double x)
        {
            return Math.acos(x) *180/Math.PI;
        }

        static double mod(double x, double lim)
        {
            return x - lim * floor(x/lim);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I love you. I compared it, and it was mostly the thing with the conversion between degrees and radians. it works now! It isnt perfectly exact, but its enough! gime your steam iD so I can gift you something nice :D

Answer (score 0):

Everone seems to link to this http://williams.best.vwh.net/sunrise_sunset_algorithm.htm
which doesn't exist anymore. Why not try something that gets updated once in a while like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_equation
Then if you like you could help edit it to make it better.